# Power View Excel, Showing more than one variable data in world map

Tags: excel, maps, powerview

I have a table with country and two more columns, like production and consumption. I am using Powerview to show the data in World Map, Is there any way to show both these data simultaneously (different color code).
At present at one time iam able to show only one of the two data columns in map.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Post a sample file with dummy data to a file sharing service (Dropbox, Onedrive, whatever) and post a link to the file here. Then -- AND THIS IS IMPORTANT -- mock up what you WANT to see as the result. Use the drawing tools to show what your desired result should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly do this with the two measures, but you can rearrange things to do it. It will produce a pie chart that contains consumption and production on each country. I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to analyze. If you are trying to compare production and consumption by country, then this may work for you. Otherwise, you will want to look into other ways of creating maps (Power Map, other Office apps for Excel, etc.)

If you rearrange your data to be

```
Country | Measure Type | Value
```

then you can put the value in the values and use Measure Type to color code. If you have access to Power Query, you can very easily unpivot the data to achieve this format.

I typed up some dummy data with columns Country, Consumption, Production and then unpivoted it and renamed a column using Power Query. Here is the M code it produced:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Country"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{{"Attribute", "Measure Type"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Then I created a new Power View report. The end result is [image]. 
If that visualization is acceptable for your purposes, then you are good to go. Otherwise, you don't have many options, since you are limited to a single layer bubble chart in Power View maps.